# How to expose Flask App with Kubernetes Ingress?

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a simple python flask app named hwrequest. I can run it from PyCharm IDE and it works fine.
I've dockerized this app using following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
LABEL maintainer="John Smith, john.smith@mycompany.com"
RUN apk update && apk add bash curl
COPY . /hwrequest
WORKDIR /hwrequest
RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["/hwrequest/app/app.py"]
```

I can exec -it into container and when I call successfully `curl 127.0.0.1:5000`
Now I'am trying to deploy this app to Kubernetes and expose it with Ingress.

This is my YAML files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: "hwrequest"
  name: "hwrequest"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "hwrequest"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "hwrequest"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "hwrequest"
        image: "myregistry.com/hwrequest:0.0.4"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "hwrequest"
  labels:
    app: "hwrequest"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: "hwrequest"
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "hwrequest"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: "hwrequest"
          servicePort: 5000
    host: "hwrequest.mycompany.com"
```

When I call `curl hwrequest.mycompany.com` I get `502 Bad Gateway`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you deployed ingress controller ? are you running k8s cluster on public cloud or locally? did you added IP address in DNS to point domain to K8s cluster ?

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-ingress-controller-overview-81abbaca19ec

Comment: which ingress you are using ? ingress nginx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exposing any application on kubernetes using ingress is non trivial task and here are few things to look for

1. Make sure that the application is listening on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`
2. The curl request should have `Host` header i.e `-H "Host: hwrequest.mycompany.com"` because this is how ingress controller will know which rule to apply as per the rules defined in ingress resource.
3. There need to a be an ingress controller such as nginx running in the cluster and the ingress controller pods need to be exposed via `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type service or can be deployed with `hostNetwork: true`
4. You need to use `NODEIP`(kubernetes node) and `NODEPORT` in curl if `NodePort` service was used so it would look like `curl http://<NODEIP>:NODEPORT -H "Host: hwrequest.mycompany.com"`.

If you used `hostNetwork` to expose nginx ingress controller pods then curl should be curl http:// -H "Host: hwrequest.mycompany.com"`

If you used `LoadBalancer` type service(works on cloud providers such as AWS,Azure,GCP) then curl should be curl http:// -H "Host: hwrequest.mycompany.com"`

If you are just starting I would suggest to look at this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) on using nginx ingress on Minikube